# MySQL not deleting referential constraint on drop of database

Tags: mysql

I dropped an entire database and am now trying to create a new database of the same name (a modified version of the old one, using an install script in case you are wondering why I am doing this).

The database fails on creation with a foreign key constraint (which is strange as the line of the sql file is way before I add constraints - the last time in the sql file).

Even stranger if I look in "information_schema" in the *referential_constraints* table I see the constraints still there from the schema I had dropped recently.

I am running MySQL community servers 8.0.22 under macOS Catalina. I have never had this behaviour that a constraint is free floating without an active schema that later invokes itself if you create a schema with that same name (note if I change the database name to any other name the SQL script loads no problem and creates the entire db)

Comment: add database and the table and remove the constraint, and then start the recovery

Comment: Ah, had tried the database by itself but the table would allow me to hammer the key itself. Thanks

Comment: Ah that failed actually: *#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint*

Comment: without seeing the hole database and the exact error message it is impossible to say, but you can check the manual for general rules